# CFMail "mailerid" attribute - What does it do?

Tags: coldfusion, gmail, email-headers, cfmail

I have a question regarding the `mailerid` attribute for the `<cfmail>` tag in Coldfusion...

According to the documentation, I understand that this dictates the `X-Mailer` header that is sent with the email. I also understand that this is typically meant to refer to the type of application/version of the mail sender.

However, what I'm not sure about are the standards involved...

According to the CF documentation the default value is `ColdFusion Application Server`, but what if I changed this to be the `cfapplication` name? I realize that non-standard header values can be interpreted as spammy, which of course I want to avoid.

I'm working through an issue currently and I think providing a unique `X-Mailer` header *may* help resolve it.

*Basically several sites on the same server using unique gmail accounts, but somehow it appears that google is creating a "session" (is that even possible?!) and not using the unique credentials to handle each email separately. Emails are crossing paths and, in some cases, ending up in the wrong inbox or with the wrong `FROM:` value.*

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html

```
mailerid

Optional

ColdFusion Application Server

Mailer ID to be passed in X-Mailer SMTP header, which identifies the mailer application.
```

You can change if you prefer to set a different program to send out your email.  By default it is ColdFusion. If you look in your spool at a mail items you will see:

```
X-Mailer:  ColdFusion 9 Application Server
```